# Open File downloaded

Tags: android

I am working at a app which is started from a browser - I am trying with FireFox - I get the file Uri from the Intent but I can not open the file in this path :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/baningmyheadreallyhard.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Any idea about why ?

Comment: And you are not showing the code which provokes that exception? Please tell what you consider to be the path.

Comment: Can you show me the code that trying to open the file ?